# ModuleNotFoundError in simple Python project

Tags: python, python-import

I create a simple python project in Pychram as shown in figure.

It works fine when I run it in Pychram.(run b_code.py, shows 'wow'/n'hellow')

However, when I'm trying to run b_code.py in terminal.

I got [**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_a'**]

Trying to google this issue but it still confuse me.

How can I fix the issue?

Thank you,

[image]

Pychram configuration:
[image]

Solution:
It works by following code

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append("..")
 from package_a import a_code
 print('wow')
 a_code.say_hellow()
```

Comment: Show us the PyCharm configuration. Note that where you run the code and how the PYTHONPATH is set up is important.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, bcode is unable to find the package. Put an **init**.py file in the root of the folder where package_a and package_b are located and bcode will know to look for the module there. As you've done inside each package.

Comment: Sorry, putting an _init_.py in the root of folder still got the error